# is there java facebook graph api for desktop?

Tags: java, facebook, desktop

Does any one implement the Desktop version with the embedded browser that can be used with the facebook graph api in java ?

Comment: If I understand all the words of your question, I can't understand it. Can you clarify it ? What do you want ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [RestFB](http://restfb.com/). Its a simple set of API written in Java.

Comment: The problem with RestFB is that it doesn't supply means to authenticate users for desktop. But see this: http://jorgecardoso.eu/blog/index.php?/archives/171-Facebook-OAuth-class-for-Processing.html with that you can get an access token and RestFB will work wonders